# Grails: Ivy: Google Code: How do I add a Google Code dependency to Grails?

Tags: maven, grails, dependencies, ivy

I'd like to get grails to automatically resolve dependencies for a Google Code project:

```
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/
```

Maven example looks as such:

```
<project>
  <repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
      <id>google-api-services</id>
      <url>http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>
    ...
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
      <version>v1beta1-rev21-1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the command I tried:

```
grails install-dependency com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:google-api-services-storage --repository=http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo
```

And the failed result:

```
There was an error resolving the dependency 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:google-api-services-storage'.
This could be because you have passed an invalid dependency name or because the dependency was not found in one of the default repositories.
Try passing a valid Maven repository with the --repository argument.
spider:cloud-storage-prototype spider$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a modern version of grails, you should add the following lines to your grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy:

`grails.project.dependency.resolution = {`

[...]

```
repositories {
```

[...]

```
    mavenRepo "http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo"
```

[...]

```
dependencies {
```

[...]

```
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1beta1-rev21-1.14.1-beta'
```

However, if you wish to instrall the dependency in your lib/ folder, you can use:

`grails install-dependency com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1beta1-rev21-1.14.1-beta --repository=http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo`